# grep a string followed with a range of numbers

Tags: regex, grep

I have this log:

```
2014-09-24 10:07:44 +0000 severity=INFO, Completed 200 OK in 955ms (Views: 566.4ms | ActiveRecord: 246.9ms)
2014-09-24 10:06:53 +0000 severity=INFO, Completed 404 Not Found in 13ms (Views: 12.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-09-24 10:06:43 +0000 severity=INFO, Completed 500 OK in 939ms (Views: 547.8ms | ActiveRecord: 253.0ms)
2014-09-24 10:05:44 +0000 severity=INFO, Completed 501 OK in 721ms (Views: 495.1ms | ActiveRecord: 198.2ms)
2014-09-24 10:04:43 +0000 severity=INFO, Completed 200 OK in 997ms (Views: 592.6ms | ActiveRecord: 238.4ms)
2014-09-24 10:03:43 +0000 severity=INFO, Completed 401 OK in 983ms (Views: 584.8ms | ActiveRecord: 237.0ms)
```

I would like to do a grep with a regular expression in order to get all lines that contains different type of errors. 
So for example:

All Client errors: Completed 4*

```
2014-09-24 10:06:53 +0000 severity=INFO, Completed 404 Not Found in 13ms (Views: 12.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-09-24 10:03:43 +0000 severity=INFO, Completed 401 OK in 983ms (Views: 584.8ms | ActiveRecord: 237.0ms)
```

All Server errors: Completed 5*

```
2014-09-24 10:06:43 +0000 severity=INFO, Completed 500 OK in 939ms (Views: 547.8ms | ActiveRecord: 253.0ms)
2014-09-24 10:05:44 +0000 severity=INFO, Completed 501 OK in 721ms (Views: 495.1ms | ActiveRecord: 198.2ms)
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```
grep 'Completed [0-9]' error.log
```

OR else to get only status codes starting with `4` and `5` use:

```
grep 'Completed [45]' error.log
```

Comment: Both commands search a given pattern in your log file. 1st pattern is: `'Completed [0-9]'` which means text `Completed` followed by any digit. And 2nd pattern is `Completed` followed by digits `4 or 5`.